# C++ std:search behavior or restriction

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm studying `std::search` (to determine if duplicates exist between `std::set`), but I don't understand the output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    set<int> a{9,10,11,12};
    set<int> b{11,12,13};
    auto it = search(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end());

    if (it != a.end())
        cout << "Common is " << *it << endl;
    else
        cout << "Oops " << *it << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So I expect `*it` would be 11, but it turns out `it!=a.end()` fails and `*it` prints some irrelevant value (4 here), and I think I might have messed up.

However, when I assign b to `{11,12}`, everything works as expected and printed out `"Common is 11"`. After some more tries, I can no longer read the pattern.

I don't know if `std::search` have this kind of restriction, and I can't find answers to it. I'm so confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search), you'll notice that `search()` is looking for an **entire subsequence**.

So here:

```
set<int> a{9,10,11,12};
set<int> b{11,12,13};
auto it = search(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end());
```

we're not looking for **any of** `11`, `12`, `13` in `a`. We're looking for **all of** them, in order. Since they're not all present in order (`a` doesn't have `13`), you get `a.end()`. Note that dereferencing the end iterator, as you're doing in your Oops case, is undefined behavior.

> However, when I assign `b` to `{11,12}`, everything works as expected

Yes, because now that entire sequence appears in `a`.

---

If you want to find **any** of the elements, just use `find_if`:

```
auto it = find_if(a.begin(), a.end(), [&](int i){ return b.count(i); });
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::search` [searches for the first occurrence of a subsequence.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search) (All of `b` must be contained in `a` for `search` to find it).

So it is normal that `it` is `a.end()`, because `b` is not contained in `a`.

It is undefined behavior to dereference `a.end()`, that's why you get a garbage value of 4.